# What is a "pseudonorm"?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, reference-request, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

The following is an excerpt of a note in topological vector spaces.

[image]

I have tried to search "semi-pseudonorm" on Google but I have got nothing so far. A search with "pseudonorm" returns what we usually call "[seminorm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Seminorm.html)". Does anybody see the term "semi-pseudonorm" or "pseudonorm" defined in the way as the note shows in other references? Or are these two concepts equivalent to something more familiar to the people working in functional analysis?

Comment: I've seen seminorm and pseudonorm used as synonyms.  I've never seen semi-pseudonorm before.

Comment: This terminology, or perhaps similar terminology, *might be* used in Eduard Cech's **Topological Spaces** (the 1966 English edition). However, my copy is at home and right now I'm not.

Comment: This morning, while at home, I looked in Cech's **Topological Spaces** and found *semi-metric*, *pseudometric*, and *semi-pseudometric* discussed extensively on pp. 299-319 and intermittently after this. The terminology used there (and I've seen it in some papers on generalized metric spaces also) is that "semi" refers to not requiring the triangle inequality and "pseudo" refers to not requiring that distinct points have a positive distance.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: Thanks a lot for the references you pointed out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to an [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/218704/14319) in MO, one can find this concept in cited references as "*F-seminorm*".